# Why is my AWS Lambda Axios request to an external API returning encoded characters?

Tags: javascript, json, aws-lambda, unicode, axios

I am trying to call an external api in an AWS lambda function with Axios and am getting some odd (unicode?) characters like this �V�LQ�R2577 as response data even though the call seems to work and return JSON in a normal express server or postman

I am trying to call an external api in an AWS lambda function with axios like so

```
let response = await axios.post(
      'https://jira.com/rest/api/2/issue', 
      payload, 
      {
        auth: {
          username: process.env.JIRA_USER,
          password: process.env.JIRA_PASS
        },
      },
    );

console.log(response.data)
```

The response data prints like this
`�V�LQ�R25771�́bũ9i@�����b+}��̢D#ݒ��������J���\�"��~bA���~fqqi�>��Z����e`

if I make the same call in postman, or in an express server, I get a response like this:

```
{
    "id": "5774175",
    "key": "PROJECT-114",
    "self": "https://jira.com/rest/api/2/issue/5774175"
}
```

I am not sure why I am getting these special characters only in AWS lambda. I want to parse the JSON response

Comment: Looks like binary. Can you inspect the response headers (eg `console.log(response.headers)`? There might be a clue in there. You could also try adding `Accept: "application/json"` into the request headers.

Comment: `”cache-control":"no-cache, no-store, no-transform","vary":"User-Agent","content-type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","transfer-encoding":"chunked","date":"Wed, 23 Nov 2022 22:49:11 GMT","connection":"close"}` Here is a sample of the response headers. adding `config: {headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'}, }` seems to have no effect

Comment: It wouldn't be under `config`, `headers` is a sibling to `auth`

Comment: @Phil good point, unfortunately the following does not seem to have any effect either
`let response = await axios.post('https://jira.com/rest/api/2/issue', payload, {auth: {username: process.env.JIRA_USER,password: process.env.JIRA_PASS},headers: { "Accept": "application/json",  "Content-Type": "application/json"},},);`

Comment: What is `payload`? Is it a plain JS object

Comment: yep something like this: `let payload = {"fields": {"project":{ "key": "PROJECT"}, ...}}`

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5296

Comment: With the number of absolutely terrible bugs Axios has had lately, I'd steer well clear. Try [got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got) instead

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about bugs in a 3rd-party library

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug with axios 1.2.x.
Here's how I fixed it without downgrading.

```
import _axios from "axios";

const axios = _axios.create({
    headers: {
        'Accept-Encoding': '*',
    }
})
```

Comment: This answer won't age well. Once Axios fixes the bug, this will need to be undone.

Comment: '*' is the default value for Accept-Encoding so this is harmless and the code serves as a good placeholder to set default headers.